# Loading Bitmap From URL

Tags: java, android

Im trying to load an image from a website into image view but nothing is loading.  Im fairly new to android so i'm probably missing something simple/stupid a step or something but I need a little help here. Note  photo[position] = www.mydomain.com/photo.png (http:// is included i just can't enter it here apparently)

```
// Locate the ImageView
        imgphoto = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.photos);
        // Capture position and set to the ImageView

        Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photo[position]);
        imgphoto.setImageBitmap(bMap);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso).
This library will do loading for you.

```
Picasso.with(context).load("http://www.yourdomain.com/photo.png").into(imageView);
```